# Apache2 and php localhost

Tags: php, windows, apache

I have installed apache2 on my windows 8 ,after it got installed i opened localhost and instead of showing it works page it showed a page with title Apache2 Ubuntu default page and though "it works" was written on it too but it has written "You should replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html) before continuing to operate your HTTP server." on it. i neglected it then and continued to install php on it and again in the end when i opened localhost it showed that page again.

Now issue is why its showing ubuntu default page when i'm installing on window secondly how to follow  "You should replace this file (located at /var/www/html/index.html) before continuing to operate your HTTP server." like where is this path on windows.?

Comment: Have you even tried to look at your file system to determine where this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Look around in C:/Program Files for an Apache folder.  If I remember, the conf files should be there and they should tell you where the html files are.

Comment: in conf there is only one file related to html named as proxy-html